# Calling an action using Ajax URL in Struts 2 - Error return is not considered

Tags: jquery

I have a project based in `Java/JEE`. I use also a `JSP Page`. In my `Java` code, i use `struts 2` to execute action and when I have an error, I must to return `error` so that my `JSP` execute the return.
The problem that in my `JSP`, the function execute always `success` even if the return is `error`.
Any solution please?

My code Java which impact with the action :

```
@Action(value = "enableFlux", results = { @Result(type = TYPE_JSON) })
public String enableFlux() {
    //Another code here

    if (trameRetour == null) {
        LOGGER.error("Trame de retour est null!);
        return error;
    } 
    else {
        return success;
    }
}
```

My JSP :

```
function enableFlux(image,idAbonnement) {       

    if(confirm("Confirmez-vous l\'activation du flux "+idAbonnement)==true){
        $.ajax({
                   type : "post",
                   url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/flux/enableFlux.action',
                   data : "idAbonnement="+idAbonnement,
                   contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                   success : function(data, status, request) {                         
                       image.src = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/styles/img/boutontrue.png";
                       $("#span"+data.abonnement.id).addClass("spanLabeltrue"); 
                       $("#span"+data.abonnement.id).removeClass("spanLabelfalse");
                   },
                   error : function(data, status, request){
                       alert ("Problème !");
                   }                     
         });
     }             
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struts 2 - Ajax - Error return is not considered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643665/struts-2-ajax-error-return-is-not-considered)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not up to date with Java/JEE but i know a little bit about jQuery.

The `success` callback is used when ever the HTTP-Header return a Statuscode 2xx (best way is 200 witch means `OK`)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

If you want jQuery to use the `error` callback you have to manipulate the HTTP-Header to return a Statuscode 4xx (Client-Error) or 5xx(Server-Error)